# how to get API data from nested array by php

Tags: php, json, api

I want to get the data from array inside array as per the below code :

```
{"address":"0x64890972513558cb4e4b4a7f8af48d892fd097b7","ETH":{"**balance**":0,"totalIn":0,"totalOut":0},"countTxs":0,"tokens":[{"**tokenInfo**":{"**address**":"0xad640689e6950b7453729a4686edb3fdfd754616","**name**":"CIChain","decimals":"18","symbol":"CIC","totalSupply":"3000000000000000000000000000","owner":"0xecb64b92ffb5179b47c87d2f105d6eeebb132c68","lastUpdated":1527246490,"issuancesCount":0,"holdersCount":31528,"**price**":false}
```

i'm using this steps but I couldn't continue :

```
    $address = "0x64890972513558cb4e4b4a7f8af48d892fd097b7"; //$_POST['address'];


$scan_url = 'https://api.ethplorer.io/getAddressInfo/'.$address.'?apiKey=freekey';
$scan_json = file_get_contents($scan_url);
$scan_array = json_decode($scan_json, true);
foreach($scan_array['tokens'] as $key => $eth) { 
    foreach($eth['tokenInfo'] as $key => $etth) {  

  echo $etth['name'];  
}}
```

I want to retrieve the marked date by stars ** into echo in php so how can I get the nested data.

Comment: try `json_decode($json)->balance`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your url given you need to change you code like below

```
$scan_array = json_decode($scan_json, true);
foreach($scan_array['tokens'] as $key => $eth) { 
    echo $eth['tokenInfo']["name"]. "\n";
}
```

[Live demo](https://eval.in/1010100)

Second `foreach` is giving all element from `tokenInfo` so either no need to use inner `foreach` or to get all element no need to use like `$etth['name']` this, only `$etth` will give is enough.

Comment: Thank you it worked fine, what if I want to get the address which is in the beginning of the array {"address":"0x64890972513558cb4e4b4a7f8af48d892fd097b7","ETH": ....... }

Comment: Just use `$scan_array["address"]`

Comment: I got this error 
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\AppServ\www\Airdrop\scan.php on line 9